# Yii2: Add local nginx proxy to request trusted hosts

Tags: php, nginx, yii2

I have nginx and php7.2-fpm installed on single Debian machine. nginx forwards requests to php through linux socks. I use yii2 which has request->trustedHosts setting. I need to add my local nginx there to be able to get x-forward-proto and other secure headers set.
Which address do I need to set up in trustedHosts? Ipv4 and Ipv6 cidr loopbacks do not help.
I just don't understand what network interface nginx uses to proxy request - loopback (127.0.0.1), some internal ip, external (internet) ip? So what is the default outbound ip nginx select to bind (should I use proxy_bind to change it to 127.0.0.1)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

request->trustedHosts setting is checked against ip address provided by $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]. So check the contents of this variable.

If your machine is behind a proxy, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] should contain proxy's ip. Try adding that ip into trustedHosts array.

(if there is no proxy and your machine is directly connected to the internet, it seems that it makes no sense to use trustedHosts. In that case $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] would contain client's ip, but you should NOT trust any client by adding "0.0.0.0/0" into trustedHosts)